# which logo you think is better for my new graphic design studio called D106?

Tags: logo, critique, branding

These are the logo options for a new graphic design/advertising agency . I have came up with two options.

The first one implies communication, approachability, the second one is a bit more design related and ''block''.

Both options are meant to be very dynamic identities where the applications, colors and usage of the logo will vary although because of the nature of each option these application have two different directions.

I am looking for an opinion on which one would be better. I am divided between the two of them.

[image]

Comment: The first looks very bland to me - like something that could be used on all the doors of a building or something - I can't really see the D without looking for it. The second approach is one I'd pursue further perhaps. I like the bubble aspect of it but might try to work with the numbers more

Comment: Thank you Zach your opinion and feedback is very much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Hi Manuel Leon, thanks for your question. Critique questions are a bit of a weird fit here, because they don't always match with our intended Q&A format. Please have a peek at [our guidelines for critique questions](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without context it would be easy to mistake the D triangle added in the second graphic with a  for a Q with the left side lopped off,

[image]

I really like the visual allusion to a speech bubble, but feel like the shape needs to read a little more clearly as a letter D.

Maybe if the top and bottom corners on the left side were a bit more square. Or perhaps a bit more of a traditional weight would help.